# No such file or directory when compiling with g++

Tags: command-line

when I compile this program

```
~/Documents/dlib-18.18/examples$ g++ -O3 -I.. ../dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 face_detection_ex.cpp
```

I get this error

```
g++: error: ../dlib/all/source.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where did you get the dlib code, and how did you install it?

Comment: if u have any idea to how to install dlibc++ for c programming not other languges on ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Well, cloning the [git repo](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) works for me on 14.04; I can't see any reason it shouldn't work on 15.10, although it's no longer a supported release

Comment: but how can i install  this Dlibc++...this Dlib can be installed by just installing the git repo

Comment: Did you try following the instructions under `COMPILING DLIB C++ EXAMPLE PROGRAMS` in the [README.txt](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) file?